# Displaying Window from STA Thread using ShowDialog()

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, mvvm, showdialog

I need to open a window from a dll project (Runs in the background or is triggered when called). For this to be possible I need to open a window from a method marked as [STAThread] to create an instance of the window.

I am using the MVVM pattern to bind the ViewModel to a View, and the view is added to the MainWindow as a usercontrol.

On the View there is a button bound to a command that 'closes' the window. The command in the ViewModel calls the CloseCommand(), which in turn will call the window.Close() method.

Code Snippet:

```
    MethodShowingTheWindow() {
        var idVM = new IDWindowViewModel();
        ShowForm<MainWindow>(idVM); // Works fine, Close Command closes the window.
        ShowForm<MainWindow>(idVM); // hits the ShowDialog() line, then just jumps to the while loop 
        ShowForm<MainWindow>(idVM);        // waiting for the thread to finish. Never displays the window.
        ShowForm<MainWindow>(idVM);

    }

    [STAThread]
    public void ShowForm<T>(IViewModel vm) {
        Thread th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate {
            var window = new MainWindow();
            window.DataContext = vm;

            vm.CloseAction = new Action(() => window.Close()); // Does this when the Close Action is called from the viewmodel (Close the window).

            try {
                window.ShowDialog();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                throw ex;
            }
        }));

        th.ApartmentState = ApartmentState.STA;
        th.Start();

        while (th.IsAlive) {
            //Wait for thread to finish
        }
    }
```

All I need to know is why the window wont appear with the second ShowWindow(idVM) call? All I can think of is that the Window is not correctly closed/Disposed. I tried adding the following to the CloseAction Action:

```
...
vm.CloseAction = new Action(() => {
    if (window is IDisposable) (window as IDisposable).Dispose();
    window.Close();
});
```

but (window is IDisposable) == false?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is my implementation for your scenario. Using Dispatcher in order to avoid STA Exceptions:

```
async Task MethodShowingTheWindow() 
{
    var idVM = new IDWindowViewModel();
    await ShowForm<MainWindow>(idVM); // Works fine, Close Command closes the window.
    await ShowForm<MainWindow>(idVM); // hits the ShowDialog() line, then just jumps to the while loop 
    await ShowForm<MainWindow>(idVM);        // waiting for the thread to finish. Never displays the window.
    await ShowForm<MainWindow>(idVM);
}

public await Task ShowForm<T>(IViewModel vm) 
{
    Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
    {
        var window = new MainWindow();
        window.DataContext = vm;
        System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            vm.CloseAction = new Action(() => window.Close());
        });
        window.ShowDialog();
    });
}
```

Comment: I am using Framework v4, so it seems like InvokeAsync is only available in 4.5. The problem doesnt look like its caused by the STAThread, I'm just not sure why the Window wont display on the second call